# Show linear program in canonical form that may be bounded doesn't necessarily contain an optimal solution which is a vertex.

Tags: linear-algebra, algorithms, linear-programming

I'm trying to show that linear program in canonical form that may be bounded doesn't necessarily contain an optimal solution which is a vertex.
I'm searching a detailed/specific Linear program in canonical form s.t. Ax <= b, that cause to contradiction. I'll be glad to hear some answers and why those linear programs show that there is no optimal solution which is a vertex.

Comment: Please provide more context for this question- how did the question arise?  What have you tried so far?  Also, be more specific about what you mean by "bounded", as there is a difference between a set of feasible points being bounded and an LP being bounded.